# Pandas: how to set column values to np.NaN if they don't match a list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
'name': ['foo','bar', '', 'blue', '', 'buzz', np.NaN ,'red', ''],
'key': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
})
df

    color   key
0   foo      1
1   bar      2
2            3
3   blue     4
4            5
5   buzz     6
6   NaN      7
7   red      8
8            9
```

I'd like to be able to set up a list and then set any values in the `name` column ***not in that list*** to NaN (along with any values that are originally blank or NaN).

The desired df would look like this:

```
values_to_keep = ['blue', 'red']

df
    color   key
0   NaN      1
1   NaN      2
2   NaN      3
3   blue     4
4   NaN      5
5   NaN      6
6   NaN      7
7   red      8
8   NaN      9
```

How would I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.loc` to [access a group of rows and columns by label(s) or a boolean array](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc).

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
... 'name': ['foo','bar', '', 'blue', '', 'buzz', np.NaN ,'red', ''],
... 'key': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
... })
>>> df
   name  key
0   foo    1
1   bar    2
2          3
3  blue    4
4          5
5  buzz    6
6   NaN    7
7   red    8
8          9
>>> values_to_keep = ['blue', 'red']
>>> df.loc[~df.name.isin(values_to_keep), 'name'] = np.nan
>>> df
   name  key
0   NaN    1
1   NaN    2
2   NaN    3
3  blue    4
4   NaN    5
5   NaN    6
6   NaN    7
7   red    8
8   NaN    9
```

Comment: thank you.   I have some blank values in the production dataset that are causing `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'loc'`

Comment: @equanimity Can you update your question with the dataset that's causing this error?

Comment: I updated it to show the blank rows.

Comment: @equanimity It's work fine with blank rows.

Comment: @equanimity Anyway I have updated my answer with the latest dataset(Including blank rows)